# Javascript check if array value exists in object value

Tags: javascript

I have an array of cars and I need to check if the car exists in the object.

```js
const cars = ["mustang", 'sonata'];

const carsObj = {
  ford: "mustang",
  audi: 'r8',
  tesla: 'model 3'
};
```

What i did so far was to check but I only know how to do it with the first element in the array exists in the object. I am looking for the fastest way to this if possible.

```
carsObj[Object.keys(carsObj).find(key => carsObj[key] === cars[0])];
```

This should return `mustang` because it is in the array and the object

Instead of checking cars [0] I need to check the entire array. Also, the array would never be that big. Maybe 5 elements the most. Is it better to loop thru the array of the object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `includes()` to search the whole array instead of just checking the first element.

Also, you can use `Object.values()` instead of `Object.keys()`, so you get the values directly, rather than having to write `carsObj[key]`

```js
const cars = ["mustang", 'sonata'];

const carsObj = {
  ford: "mustang",
  audi: 'r8',
  tesla: 'model 3'
};
console.log(Object.values(carsObj).find(val => cars.includes(val)))
```

Answer (score 0):

you need just values of your object not keys:

```
let values = Object.values(carsObj);
```

it will give you array of values  => [ mustang,r8,model 3]
then use forEach method

```
cars.forEach((car)=> {
  const found =   values.find((value)=> value === car)
}
```